# I ruined my mesh topology

Tags: mesh, topology

idk how did that happen, I literally ruined my mesh.

can any one help me ?

[image]

Comment: Detach the mesh from the armature, and have a look if the problem persists. If so, fix the geometry. Might also be a shading problem. If not, fix the weighting.

Comment: What is it that happened exactly? Is it the shading, or the triangles (which in turn will cause shading issues)?

Comment: please share your file (at least this object): https://pasteall.org/blend/